# How do I load a very large file in my DC.js chart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, frontend, dc.js, crossfilter

I have a .csv file that carries data from New Zealand Earthquakes.

I have 01 map, 03 graphs and 01 table that carry this data. Which are divided by Number of events per magnitude, Events per depth (km) and Events per hour.

The .csv file has 15,441 lines and is giving an error saying `Maximum call stack size exceeded`. Which is strange, because I'm using DC.js and crossfilter, and theoretically this library is used to handling millions of data.

Attached is the image with the error you are giving:

[image]

If I take 10,000 lines out of this file, the code works normally, but the problem is that I need the entire file. "/

I'm putting my code here, as the .csv file is very large, I couldn't simulate it on Stackblitz, CodePen, Plunker, JSFiddle, etc. I apologize.

This code I'm trying to do like this link: https://alexandrecajamos.github.io/datavis-course/2017_11_20/earthquakes.html

The earthquakes.csv file if you can download it is here:https://github.com/bernalvinicius/dc-charts/blob/master/earthquakes.csv

Here is my code, thank you in advance.

```js
var magnitudeChart = dc.barChart('#barMagnitudeChart');
var depthChart = dc.barChart('#barDepthChart');
var timeChart = dc.lineChart('#lineTimeChart');
var dataTable = dc.dataTable('#myTable');

var markers = d3.map();
var markerLayer = L.layerGroup();
var idDimension, idGrouping;

var map = L.map('map').setView([-41.05, 172.93], 5);
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
    maxZoom: 17
}).addTo(map);
map.on('moveend', updateFilters);

var url = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/bernalvinicius/64aa48728dc717c71906742ca2833d17/raw/5244a987b974e8352809dc16e98926e2c6889ba1/earthquakes.csv';    
d3.csv(url).then(function (data) {

    data.forEach(function (d) {
        d.dtg = d.origintime.substr(0, 19);
        d.lat = +d.latitude;
        d.long = +d.longitude;
        d.mag = d3.precisionRound(+d.magnitude, 1);
        d.depth = d3.precisionRound(+d.depth, 0);
        var size = d.mag * 10000;
        var circle = L.circle([d.lat, d.long], d.mag * 5000, {
            color: '#fd8d3c',
            weight: 2,
            fillColor: '#fecc5c',
            fillOpacity: 0.5
        });
        circle.bindPopup("Magnitude: " + d.mag + "<br>Time: " + d.dtg);
        circle.publicid = d.publicid;
        markers.set(d.publicid, circle);
    });

    console.log(data);

    var myCrossfilter = crossfilter(data);

    idDimension = myCrossfilter.dimension(function (d) {
        return d.publicid;
    });
    idGrouping = idDimension.group(function (id) {
        return id;
    });

    var dateDimension = myCrossfilter.dimension(function (d) {
        return d.dtg;
    });

    var magDimension = myCrossfilter.dimension(function (d) {
        return d.mag;
    });
    var magDimensionCount = magDimension.group();

    var depthDimension = myCrossfilter.dimension(function (d) {
        return d.depth;
    });
    var depthDimensionCount = depthDimension.group();

    var hourDimension = myCrossfilter.dimension(function (d) {
        return d3.timeHour(d.dtg);
    });
    var hourDimensionCount = hourDimension.group();

    magnitudeChart
        .width(480)
        .height(150)
        .margins({ top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 40 })
        .dimension(magDimension)
        .group(magDimensionCount)
        .transitionDuration(500)
        .centerBar(true)
        .gap(56)
        .x(d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 8]))
        .elasticY(true)
        .on("filtered", function (chart, filter) {
            updateMarkers();
        });

    depthChart
        .width(600)
        .height(150)
        .margins({ top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 40 })
        .dimension(depthDimension)
        .group(depthDimensionCount)
        .transitionDuration(500)
        .centerBar(true)
        .gap(1)
        .x(d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 100]))
        .elasticY(true)
        .on("filtered", function (chart, filter) {
            updateMarkers();
        });

    timeChart.width(960)
        .height(150)
        .transitionDuration(500)
        .margins({ top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 40 })
        .dimension(hourDimension)
        .group(hourDimensionCount)
        .brushOn(false)
        .elasticY(true)
        .x(d3.scaleTime().domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) { return d.dtg; })));

    dataTable
        .width(960)
        .height(800)
        .dimension(dateDimension)
        .group(function (d) {
            return "Earthquake Table";
        })
        .size(10)
        .columns([
            function (d) { return d.dtg; },
            function (d) { return d.mag; },
            function (d) { return d.depth; },
            function (d) { return d.lat; },
            function (d) { return d.long; }])
        .sortBy(function (d) { return d.dtg; })
        .order(d3.ascending);

    dc.renderAll();
    updateMarkers();

});

function updateMarkers() {
    var ids = idGrouping.all();
    var todisplay = new Array(ids.length);
    var mc = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
        var tId = ids[i];
        if (tId.value > 0) {
            todisplay[mc] = markers.get(tId.key);
            mc = mc + 1;
        }
    }
    todisplay.length = mc;
    markerLayer.clearLayers();
    if (map.hasLayer(markerLayer)) {
        map.removeLayer(markerLayer);
    }
    markerLayer = L.layerGroup(todisplay).addTo(map);
}

function updateFilters() {
    var ids = idGrouping.all();
    var visibleMarkers = new Array(ids.length);
    var cout = 0;

    markerLayer.eachLayer(function (layer) {
        if (map.getBounds().contains(layer.getLatLng())) {
            visibleMarkers[cout] = layer.publicid;
            cout++;
        }
    });
    markerLayer.length = cout;

    idDimension.filterFunction(function (d) {
        return visibleMarkers.indexOf(d) > -1;
    });
    dc.redrawAll();
}
```

```html
<head>
    <style>
        #map {
            width: 650px;
            height: 450px;
        }
    </style>

    <title>Earthquake Data</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
        integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dc/2.1.8/dc.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crossfilter/1.3.12/crossfilter.js"></script>

    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dc/3.1.8/dc.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <div class='container-fluid'>
        <h3>Earthquakes in New Zealand</h3>

        <div id="map"></div>
        <div id="barMagnitudeChart">
            <span>
                <h4> Number of Events by Magnitude
                    <a href="javascript:dc.magnitudeChart.filterAll(); dc.redrawAll();" style="display: none;">Reset</a>
                </h4>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div id="barDepthChart">
            <span>
                <h4> Events by Depth (km)
                    <a href="javascript:dc.depthChart.filterAll(); dc.redrawAll();" style="display: none;">Reset</a>
                </h4>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div id="lineTimeChart">
            <h4> Events per hour </h4>
        </div>
        <table class="table table-hover" id="myTable">
            <thead>
                <tr class="header">
                    <th>DTG</th>
                    <th>Magnitude</th>
                    <th>Depth</th>
                    <th>Latitude</th>
                    <th>Longitude</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>

    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: It’s likely that you have missing or null fields that you only see when you try more rows. Please see [this crossfilter gotcha](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/Crossfilter-Gotchas#natural-ordering-of-dimension-and-group-values). It would be nice (and would probably save hours of frustration) [if crossfilter validated the data and accessors on load](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/issues/69), but it does not.

Comment: Hello @Gordon, From what I saw everything is fine with my file, I managed to put everything in `Git Gist` and now I updated my code with the right link. If you can see I changed it, thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I dunno, that's what this error means, so I think you will need to look very closely at each of the dimensions you are defining and make sure that all the fields you are using are naturally ordered as described in the link I posted earlier. To narrow in on it, you could temporarily remove some of the dimensions and see where it fails. There isn't really a general how-to question here, it is most likely a data issue.

Comment: I'm going to do this to test the dimensions separately, so I think I can figure out the problem. Because in the example that is working and I'm trying to copy, it works without any problem with the 15,411 lines. Thanks for the help